# How to find the codes inside the functions in "frequencyconnectedness" package?

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to understand the lines of codes constructing the "spilloverrollingBK12to" function in "frequencconnectedness" package.

I downloaded the frequencconnectedness.tar zip folder from github and opened all the scripts.

I want to change some elements inside the functions body and run the codes again.

Maybe use the elements inside the function as a script.

I will appreciate any suggestions. Please

Comment: Hi. I am trying to see the complete body of code that makes up spilloverRollingBK12to or SpilloverRollingBK12. Inside the files I only see the description of the functions. I do not see the codes constructing the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function name (`spilloverrollingBK12to`) in this package. However, there is a `spilloverRollingBK12` function in file `R/spilloverRolling.R`, [line 150](https://github.com/tomaskrehlik/frequencyConnectedness/blob/master/R/spilloversRolling.R#L150).

Comment: Hi....thank you for your responses. Yap, SpilloverRollingBK12to I have already used. I checked inside spilloverRolling.R. I do not see the algorithm. Would you be kind enough to put the script up here?

Comment: @R.Islam you can follow the functions. Find [spilloverRolling](https://github.com/tomaskrehlik/frequencyConnectedness/blob/master/R/spilloversRolling.R#L21) which fetches the function using `get("spilloverBK12")`. If you search for `spilloverBK12` you will get [here](https://github.com/tomaskrehlik/frequencyConnectedness/blob/a5ac5f8708cc6f91cb54428563062aa327dc3e5e/R/spillovers.R#L155) which calls `spilloverFft("fftGenFEVD"...)` and so on...

Comment: I could not find the algorithm constructing spilloverFft function. The whole thing in here is in functions. Can you please show me how to find the complete algorithm constructing these functions?

Comment: Or maybe you can post the algorithms here>

Comment: The functions lead me to other functions. Unlike MATLAB I cannot trace the body inside the functions. Help me put here to get the complete body of the function constructing spilloverBK12